# Extract values and attributes from a list and convert them into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, text-mining

I got the following list for my model:

```
List of 9
 $ phi           : num [1:5, 1:1500] 1.8e-04 1.8e-04 1.8e-04 1.8e-04 1.8e-04 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "t_1" "t_2" "t_3" "t_4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:1500] "word1" "word2" "word3" "word4" ...
 $ theta         : num [1:500, 1:5] 0.1234 0.4567 0.01234 0.04567 0.02345 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:500] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "t_1" "t_2" "t_3" "t_4" ...
 $ gamma         : num [1:5, 1:1500] 0.20 0.70 0.10 0.1 0.11 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "t_1" "t_2" "t_3" "t_4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:1500] "word1" "word2" "word3" "word4" ...
 $ data          :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ i       : int [1:10000] 1234 6789 2233 1367 1123 1123 145 145 156 1325 ...
  .. ..@ p       : int [1:1500] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 1234 1500
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:500] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:1500] "word1" "word2" "word3" "word4" ...
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:100000] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ alpha         : Named num [1:5] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1  ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "t_1" "t_2" "t_3" "t_4" ...
 $ beta          : Named num [1:1500] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1500] "word1" "word2" "word3" "word4"
```

Is there a way of how to select $theta and all its attributes and save them as a data frame? In other words, I want to extract this part from the list:

```
$ theta         : num [1:500, 1:5] 0.1234 0.4567 0.01234 0.04567 0.02345 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:500] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "t_1" "t_2" "t_3" "t_4" ...
```

and have a dataframe that looks like this (the column order does not matter):

```
Theta  | var1 | var2 |
0.1234 | 1    | t_1  |
0.4567 | 2    | t_2  |
0.01234| 3    | t_3  |
```

I have tried `lapply` and many other suggestions that I found in terms of list extraction  but failed to extract the part shown above.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: If it is a `list`, then just do `out <- lst1$theta`

Comment: What happens if you do list$theta or list[2]

Comment: @MrFlick Unfortunately, I was not sure how to make a "reproducable" example out of the nested list that I got as an output from my LDA model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already metioned in comments, you can easily access $theta with list subsetting either `model$theta` or `model[['theta']]`.

$theta is a numeric matrix 500 x 5. To convert it into desirable format just melt it:

```
theta_matrix = model$theta
theta_df = reshape2::melt(theta_matrix, value.name = "Theta")
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice answer, megamad - upvoted. I didn't get that the OP wanted a length 1500 dataframe in this format - I thought it was maybe a misunderstanding of the structure of the list, but it turns out I just misunderstood the question!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `theta` is a 500 x 5 numeric matrix, so the data frame will have 500 rows and 5 columns named `t_1`, `t_2`, `t_3`, `t_4` and `t_5` - it won't be a 3 - row data frame as in your expected output.

Assuming your list is called `my_list`, here's how you get `theta` as a data frame:

```
as.data.frame(my_list$theta)
```

Or perhaps

```
setNames(as.data.frame(my_list$theta), attr(my_list$theta, "dimnames")[[2]])
```

Comment: hey allan! thank you so much - that was really helpful. I guess I was confused about the whole lapply and list referencing topic that I did not think of just trying to reference to the list element by "list_name$theta."

For this example I used the df as described by megamad. However, your answer was also very helpful since I need the version you created for other variables.